# What should I do with vector icon to apply it to the ApplicationBarIconButton

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I mean, say, I have the following code, which represents an icon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Canvas 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
x:Name="appbar_information_circle" Width="76" Height="76" 
Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
<Path Width="38" Height="38" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="19" Stretch="Fill" 
Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 38,19C 48.4934,19 57,27.5066 "/>
```

How to set the result to the ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri?

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done. Here is a wpdev.uservoice request that you can upvote if you want to see this functionality added.
http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/2643929-vector-tiles-app-list-icons-and-app-bar-icons